# Отправка письма из приложения winforms через веб-браузер

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Я новичок в программировании. В своем приложении я использую возможность отправить письмо при нажатии на label.

```
private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Process.Start("mailto:" + "****@ru.*****.com" + "?subject=Приложение - ********" + "&body=" + "Добрый день! **************");
}
```

Все работает но только есть один нюанс. Если у пользователя есть полная лицензия на Outlook. Откроется приложение с готовой формой для отправки. А если пользователь имеет доступ только через веб интерфейс Outlook 365 то у него не получится. Как мне сделать так чтобы при нажатии открывалась веб страница(почтовый ящик) с готовой формой для отправки (адрес получателя, тема, текст письма).
Заранее прошу простить если что то не так написал и спасибо за понимание (просьба не отправлять меня учить мат.часть а просто помочь в достижении поставленной задачи).

Comment: В системе надо указать другой обработчик диплинок mailto

Comment: Обработчики диплинка по идее зарегистрированы в реестре. Там можно найти, если обработчика нет, то вызывать браузер. Еще лучше, так как для пользователей эта ситуация может быть своя уникальная, то можно способ отправки писем вынести в настройки приложения в виде шаблона типа `mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}` в текстбоксе. При желании пользователь туда хоть `https://` ссылку должен иметь возможность вбить.

Comment: Проблема в том что я (писал уже об этом) новичок в программировании. И не совсем все понял. Если можно и не затруднит более подробнее описать(разжевать) вышесказанное Вами.

Comment: Нашел вариант решения: используя все тот же Process.Start можно запустить встроенный в WIN 10 почтовый клиент  - Process.Start("outlookmail:");
 Но как сделать чтобы открывалось новое письмо с адресом  получателя и темой письма не знаю.